# Creating a staticmethod that creates a class of its own by default using python

Tags: python, object

I know this is probably not a good style, but I was wondering if it is possible to construct a class when a static method is called

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "this worked"

    @staticmethod
    def test_class(var=myClass().variable):
        print self.variable


if "__name__" == "__main__":
    myClass.test_class()
```

Right now it returns

```
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined
```

Here is what I am suspecting, in default, the python interpreter will scan the class and register each function, when it register the function, it checks the function's default variable, the default variable have to be defined?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest is to turn it into a `classmethod` instead:

```
class myClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "this worked"

    @classmethod
    def test_class(cls):
        var = cls().variable
        print var

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myClass.test_class()
```

See [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

It is not entirely clear from your question what the use case is; it could well be that there's a better way to do what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default value for a function argument has to be definable at the point that the function appears, and a class isn't actually finished defining until the end of the "class block."  The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is:

```
@staticmethod
def test_class(var=None):
    if var is None: var = myClass().variable
    print var  # I assume this is what you meant to write for this line; otherwise, the function makes no sense.
```

This has the one downside that you can't pass `None` to `myClass.test_class` and get it to print out.  If you want to do this, try:

```
@staticmethod
def test_class(*vars):
     if len(vars) == 0:
         var = myClass().variable
     #elif len(vars) > 1:
         # Throw an error yelling at the user for calling the function wrong (optional)
     else:
         var = vars[0]
     print var
```